# Prove that an Interval I is closed and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm attempting to prove the following statement:

> Let $I$ be a non-trivial interval over the real numbers. Show that if every *continuous* function on $I$ is uniformly continuous, then $I$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: Can I use the equivalence between "closed and bounded" and "compact"?

Comment: Do you mean every continuous $f$ over $I$ is uniformly continuous ?

Comment: i have not reached compact definition, and @fardad, yes, im sorry, it's like you said, im going to edit it now.

Comment: It's true for trivial intervals too, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but i need the proof for an non-trivial interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ is unbounded, for example $I = (a, \infty)$, then $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continuous -- a contradiction.

If $I$ is not closed , for example $I = (a, b) $, then $f(x) = 1/(x-a)$ is uniformly continuous -- a contradiction.

Comment: that really helps to get the idea, to see that is true, but my teacher always says to us, that to proof something we need to use all the hypothesis, so, do you have any idea how to use them?

Comment: This is proof by contradiction.  I'm using all the hypotheses. Assume I is not closed and bounded. Then I is either not closed or not bounded.  In each case produce a continuous function that is not uniformly continuous. Then conclude the assumption is false.

Comment: oh, ok i see,thanks for your answer i appreciate it!

Comment: @Zigisfredo: you're welcome.  You only have to find one unbounded interval and continuous function where this is false. Likewise for non-closed intervals.